# Javascript mask string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am creating a ASP.NET web app and I need to mask the input string in a textbox. The string needs to be masked like:

DR117-17

So, two characters(DR), followed by 3 digits, followed by a '-' and followed by the fiscal year(yy).

The user has to actually input only the 3 digits (ex:'117').

The perfect solution would be that the characters 'DR' are automatically inserted on click, then wait for three digits to be input and then automatically add the '-17'.

Comment: How about using the Jquery Mask Plugin? http://jsfiddle.net/55003z11/

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `jQuery` `mask` plugin is pretty straightforward:

```
$("#date").mask("DR999-17");
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55003z11/